# Qt/QML: Is it allowed to have a model view as a delegate?

Tags: qt, listview, model-view-controller, qml

Is it possible to have a model view (such as ListView or GridView) in a delegate of another model view?

I'm using a ListView (LV1) whose delegate also has a ListView (LV2). Everything before and after LV2 is displayed correctly (and that's in the delegate of LV1). However, nothing is shown in LV1.

My model is from this: http://qt-project.org/wiki/How_to_use_a_QSqlQueryModel_in_QML . I suppose that the SQL query is correct since it returns the correct information when ran externally to Qt. According to debug messages, that all queries is clearly executed.

I have two queries, one being updated with the other. That works good.

Figure #1 shows the debug messages, and it points out that the QML does call the data function and information is indeed returned from the database.

Figure #2 shows the QML window at the time of figure #1: we can clearly see that the layout is messed up and nothing is shown.

Verbatim #1 is the QML code.

Verbatim #2 is an excerpt of the main which shows that I connect the *main* model to the secondary model though a signal called updateBindings.

Verbatim #3 is my updated SqlQueryModel. The main difference with the tutorial is the signal and slots.

Verbatim #4 is for reference, since this class is used in verbatim #3.

Any input is valued, I've been struggling with this for a few days now. Thanks.

Verbatim #1 (QML):

```
import QtQuick 1.1

import "Styles"

Rectangle {
    id : window;
    width : 750
    height : 500
    signal searchSignal(string msg)
    signal resetSignal()
    property variant subtypes: {"S":"Status (digital)", "V":"Value (analog)"}
    property variant phases: {'66': 'Final Mass Properties', '67': 'Final Thruster Aignment/Solar Array Inst.', '60': 'Final Functional Performance', '114': 'Maneuver (Wheel Mode) Overlay (LTO)', '88': 'Troubleshooting Test Phase 9', '89': 'Troubleshooting Test Phase 10', '111': 'Battery 1 Reconditioning Overlay (LTO)', '110': 'Battery Recharge Overlay (LTO)', '113': 'Maneuver (SK Mode) Overlay (LTO)', '112': 'Battery 2 Reconditioning Overlay (LTO)', '68': 'Flight Battery Functional', '83': 'Troubleshooting Test Phase 4', '80': 'Troubleshooting Test Phase 1', '81': 'Troubleshooting Test Phase 2', '86': 'Troubleshooting Test Phase 7', '87': 'Troubleshooting Test Phase 8', '84': 'Troubleshooting Test Phase 5', '85': 'Troubleshooting Test Phase 6', '24': 'Post T/V Performance ( Ambient)', '26': 'Alignments -  Pre Dynamics', '27': 'Antenna Installation', '20': 'Cold (Equinox) Functional Plateau', '21': 'Transition Monitor (cold to hot)', '22': 'Hot ( Winter Solstice)', '82': 'Troubleshooting Test Phase 3', '28': 'Solar Array Installation', '40': 'CATR', '41': 'ESD  (PFM Only)', '1': 'North Panel Electrical integration', '3': 'SSM/Bus Module Electrical Integration', '2': 'South Panel Electrical integration', '5': 'South and bus Electrical Integration', '4': 'North and Bus Electrical integration', '6': 'S/C Electrical Integration', '75': 'Hazardous Processing Facility Operations', '39': 'Final Alignment Verif. CATR Preps', '77': 'Launch Complex Performance', '76': 'HPF Payload testing', '108': 'Lunar Eclipse Event Overlay (LTO)', '109': 'Battery Discharge Overlay (LTO)', '70': 'Launch Base Functional Performance', '102': 'On Orbit', '103': 'Station Keeping', '100': 'Prime Shift Orbit Raising', '101': 'Off Shift Orbit Raising', '106': 'Quiescent Non-Eclipse State of Health (LTO)', '107': 'Earth Eclipse Season Overlay (LTO)', '104': 'Eclipse', '105': 'Post Eclipse', '10': 'Panel RF Testing', '13': 'Integrated System Reference Performance', '12': 'End to End Satting', '15': 'Transition Monitoring (Ambient to Hot Solstice)', '14': 'Pre Thermal Vacuum performance (Ambient)', '16': 'Summer Solstice Functional Plateau', '18': 'Transition Monitoring (Hot to Cold)', '31': 'Sine Vibration', '30': 'Acoustic Vibration', '36': 'Post Dynamics Performance', '35': 'Deployments', '34': 'Launch Vehicle Adapter Fit Check', '65': 'Propulsion Global Helium'}

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        focus: true
        highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange
        orientation: ListView.Horizontal
        snapMode: ListView.SnapOneItem
        model: tcModel
        delegate: Component {
            Item {
                id: item
                width: window.width; height: window.height

                Flickable {
                    id: mainScrollView
                    contentHeight: parent.height
                    contentWidth: parent.width
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    clip: true
                    focus: true
                    interactive: true
                    Column{
                        id: dataCol
                        spacing: 10
                        /* Buttons */

                        Row{
                            width: window.width
                            Button{
                                text: "Go"
                                action.onClicked: searchSignal("TLM_NO LIKE '" + num.text + "%'")
                                bgColor: "lightgreen"
                                width: window.width/10; height: window.width/30
                            }

                            Button{
                                text: "Reset"
                                action.onClicked: resetSignal()
                                bgColor: "lightgrey"
                                width: window.width/10; height: window.width/30
                            }
                        }

                        /* */
                        Grid{

                            columns: 5
                            spacing: 10

                            Text {
                                text: "Mnemonic"
                                font.bold: true
                            }

                            Text {
                                text: "Name"
                                font.bold: true
                            }

                            Text {
                                text: "Type"
                                font.bold: true
                            }

                            Text {
                                text: "Subtype"
                                font.bold: true
                            }

                            Text {
                                text: "Category"
                                font.bold: true
                            }
                            /* NEW LINE */
                            TextEdit {
                                id: num
                                text: TLM_NO
                            }

                            Text {
                                text: TLM_NAME
                            }

                            Text {
                                text: TLM_TYPE
                            }

                            Text {
                                text: (SUBTYPE ? subtypes[SUBTYPE] : "Unknown")
                            }

                            Text {
                                text: TLM_CATEGO
                            }
                        } /* End grid */

                        Separator{}

                        Text{
                            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                            text: "<u>Limits</u>"
                            id: limitLabel
                        }

                        /* Limits */
                        ListView {
                            //anchors.top: limitLabel.bottom
                            header:
                                Row{
                                height: 30
                                clip: true
                                anchors.margins: 4
                                Text {
                                    text: "Phase name"
                                    font.bold: true
                                }

                                Text {
                                    text: "Red low"
                                    font.bold: true
                                }

                                Text {
                                    text: "Yellow low"
                                    font.bold: true
                                }

                                Text {
                                    text: "Yellow high"
                                    font.bold: true
                                }

                                Text {
                                    text: "Red high"
                                    font.bold: true
                                }
                            }

                            delegate: Item {
                                id: delegate
                                width: delegate.ListView.view.width;
                                height: 30
                                clip: true
                                anchors.margins: 4

                                Row {
                                    anchors.margins: 4
                                    anchors.fill: parent
                                    spacing: 4;

                                    Text {
                                        text: PHASE_NO?phases[PHASE_NO]:"N/A"
                                    }

                                    Text {
                                        text: CRIT_LO?CRIT_LO:"N/A"
                                    }

                                    Text {
                                        text: NOM_LO?NOM_LO:"N/A"
                                    }

                                    Text {
                                        text: NOM_HI?NOM_HI:"N/A"
                                    }

                                    Text {
                                        text: CRIT_HI?CRIT_HI:"N/A"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            model: limitModel
                            height: window.height / 3
                        } /* End limits grid view*/
                        Separator{}

                        Text{
                            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                            text: "end limits"
                        }
                    }/* End column*/
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Verbatim #2 (main.cpp , excerpt):

```
/* Let's create all the models associated with this given user form.*/
/* We need the viewer to connect all the signals and to set context properties.*/
QmlApplicationViewer viewer;
SqlQueryModel *mainModel;

QList<SqlQueryModel*>::iterator umIt;
QHash<QString, SqlQueryModel*> modelCnx = QHash<QString, SqlQueryModel*>();

for(umIt = selectedUF.userModels.begin(); umIt != selectedUF.userModels.end(); umIt++){

    SqlQueryModel *model = *umIt;
    /* Let's go through each binding of the UserModel and connect create the bindings in the model. */
    model->exec();
    viewer.rootContext()->setContextProperty(model->modelName, model);

    /* If this is the selected search model, let's save it to connect the signals later. */
    if (model->modelName == selectedUF.searchModel){
        mainModel = model;
    }else{
        QObject::connect(mainModel, SIGNAL(bindedValueChanged(QString, QString, QVariant)),
                         model, SLOT(updateBindings(QString,QString,QVariant)));
    }
}

viewer.setMainQmlFile(QString("qml/" + selectedUF.qml));

QObject::connect((QObject*)viewer.rootObject(), SIGNAL(searchSignal(QString)),
                 mainModel, SLOT(search(QString)));

QObject::connect((QObject*)viewer.rootObject(), SIGNAL(resetSignal()),
                 mainModel, SLOT(reset()));

viewer.showExpanded();

return app->exec();
```

Verbatim #3 (sqlquerymodel.cpp):

```
#include "sqlquerymodel.h"

SqlQueryModel::SqlQueryModel(QObject *parent) :
    QSqlQueryModel(parent)
{
    this->modelName = "";
    this->query = "";
    bindings = QHash<QString, QList<ModelBinding> >();
}

void SqlQueryModel::setQuery(const QString &query, const QSqlDatabase &db)
{
    if(query.length() == 0){
        this->query = query;
    }

    QSqlQueryModel::setQuery(query, db);
    generateRoleNames();

    QSqlError le = this->lastError();

    if (le.isValid()){
        QString errMsg("Query was:\n%1\n\nError:\n%2");
        QMessageBox::critical(0, "Query error", errMsg.arg(query).arg(le.text()));
        return;
    }

}

void SqlQueryModel::setQuery(const QSqlQuery &query)
{
    QSqlQueryModel::setQuery(query);
    generateRoleNames();

    QSqlError le = this->lastError();

    if (le.isValid()){
        QString errMsg("Query was:\n%1\n\nError:\n%2");
        qDebug() << errMsg.arg(query.lastQuery()).arg(le.text());
        /* We're not using a MessageBox because it causes a segfault for some reason. */
        //QMessageBox::critical(0, "Query error", errMsg.arg(query.lastQuery()).arg(le.text()));
        return;
    }

}
/**
 * @brief SqlQueryModel::exec This function prepares and executes the query.
 */
void SqlQueryModel::exec()
{
    qDebug() << "Executing query on model" << this->modelName;
    /* Let's create a QSqlQuery. It will store the query and we'll bind values to it.*/
    QSqlQuery sQuery;
    /* If we initialize the query with the string, then we CANNOT use bind (won't work and won't show any error).*/
    sQuery.prepare(this->query);

    /** Now, let's go through all the models associated to this instance.
     * For each of them, we'll bind its value. Note that we're avoiding making a copy by using the adresses
     * cf. : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106243/qt-iterator-not-accessing-the-correct-object
    **/

    QHash<QString, QList<ModelBinding> >::iterator bindingsIt;
    for (bindingsIt = bindings.begin(); bindingsIt != bindings.end(); bindingsIt++){
        QList<ModelBinding>::iterator eachBindingIt;
        QList<ModelBinding>& curBinding = *bindingsIt;

        for(eachBindingIt = curBinding.begin(); eachBindingIt != curBinding.end(); eachBindingIt++){

            ModelBinding& binding = *eachBindingIt;
            binding.bindToQuery(&sQuery);
        }
    }

    /* Let's not forget to execute this query, or nothing will be displayed in the QML. */
    sQuery.exec();
    qDebug() << "----------------";
    qDebug() << sQuery.lastQuery();
    QMapIterator<QString, QVariant> i(sQuery.boundValues());
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        i.next();
        qDebug() << i.key().toAscii().data() << "="
                 << i.value().toString().toAscii().data();
    }
    qDebug() << "----------------";
    this->setQuery(sQuery);
}

void SqlQueryModel::generateRoleNames()
{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames;
    for( int i = 0; i < record().count(); i++) {
        roleNames[Qt::UserRole + i + 1] = record().fieldName(i).toAscii();
    }

    qDebug() << "Generating role names for" << modelName;

    setRoleNames(roleNames);
}

void SqlQueryModel::search(QString str){

    QString nQuery (query);
    nQuery.append(" WHERE ").append(str);
    qDebug() << "Set query to: " << nQuery;
    this->setQuery(nQuery);
    QSqlError le = this->lastError();

    if (le.isValid()){
        QString errMsg("An error occurred while loading the file.\n\nQuery was:\n%1\n\nError:\n%2");
        QMessageBox::critical(0, "Database error", errMsg.arg(nQuery).arg(le.text()));
    }
}

QVariant SqlQueryModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{

    QVariant value = QSqlQueryModel::data(index, role);
    if(role < Qt::UserRole){
        value = QSqlQueryModel::data(index, role);
    }else{
        int columnIdx = role - Qt::UserRole - 1;
        QModelIndex modelIndex = this->index(index.row(), columnIdx);
        value = QSqlQueryModel::data(modelIndex, Qt::DisplayRole);

        qDebug() << modelName << ":" << record().fieldName(columnIdx) << "=" << value;

        emit bindedValueChanged(modelName, record().fieldName(columnIdx), value);
    }
    return value;
}

void SqlQueryModel::reset()
{
    qDebug() << "Resetting original SQL query to: " << query;
    this->setQuery(query);
}

void SqlQueryModel::updateBindings(QString modelName, QString col, QVariant val)
{

    /** Now, let's go through all the models associated to this instance.
     * We're going to see if the new signal we got is used for this model (for model name and column name).
     * If so, we'll assigned it and then we'll execute this query by calling exec().
    **/

    bool anyValueChanged = false;

    QHash<QString, QList<ModelBinding> >::iterator bindingsIt;

    for (bindingsIt = bindings.begin(); bindingsIt != bindings.end(); bindingsIt++){

        QList<ModelBinding>::iterator eachBindingIt;
        QList<ModelBinding>& curBinding = *bindingsIt;

        for(eachBindingIt = curBinding.begin(); eachBindingIt != curBinding.end(); eachBindingIt++){

            ModelBinding& binding = *eachBindingIt;
            if(bindingsIt.key() == modelName && binding.column == col){
                binding.value = val;
                anyValueChanged = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if (anyValueChanged){
        this->exec();
    }
}
```

Verbatim #4 (modelbinding.cpp):

```
#include "modelbinding.h"

ModelBinding::ModelBinding(QString placeholder, QString column, QVariant value)
{
    this->placeholder = placeholder;
    this->column = column;
    this->value = value;
}

void ModelBinding::bindToQuery(QSqlQuery *sQuery)
{
    sQuery->bindValue(placeholder, value);
}
```

[image: Figure #1]
[image: Figure #2]

Answer (score 1):

The item in your base ListView delegate is sized to the window's height and width. I believe this would effectively hide any other delegates from the root level ListView because the first delegate would take up the entire screen.

Comment: I tried setting the height to a specific pixel size. It only added a blank space, not even "N/A". Any other thought? Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: Can you post code showing us what your models look like? You definitely have an issue with your delegate being sized to the window size. It may be that you wanted to use a different component here instead of a ListView.

Comment: I've added a bunch of information. Let me know if that is of any help. Thanks again for your interest in this problem.